The modal automatically closes in React Native even though the state is still true
I created media-selector, media-form, and camera with the following purpose: After capturing a photo, the uri is sent to media-selector via a prop (the camera modal will close), and then the media-form modal appears to input information about the captured photo.
However, when I reach the media-form step, clicking on any text input inside the media-form causes the form to automatically close. The only time the photo is properly returned is when I click the Save button on the media-form (but I can't fill in any information ).
Code media-selector
interface MediaSelectorProps {
  onMediaSelected: (uri: string, type: 'photo' | 'video', des: string, coordinates: { lat: number, lng: number }) => void;
}

const MediaSelector: React.FC<MediaSelectorProps> = ({ onMediaSelected }) => {
  const [isModalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [showCamera, setShowCamera] = useState(false);
  const [showMediaForm, setShowMediaForm] = useState(false);
  const [capturedMedia, setCapturedMedia] = useState<{ uri: string; type: 'photo' | 'video' } | null>(null);

  const handleCameraPress = () => {
    setModalVisible(false);
    setShowCamera(true);
  };

  const handleGalleryPress = () => {
    launchImageLibrary({ mediaType: 'mixed' }, (response) => {
      if (response.assets && response.assets.length > 0) {
        const asset = response.assets[0];
        if (asset.uri) {
          setCapturedMedia({ uri: asset.uri, type: asset.type === 'video' ? 'video' : 'photo' });
          setShowMediaForm(true);
        }
      }
    });
    setModalVisible(false);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("showMediaForm changed:", showMediaForm);
  }, [showMediaForm]);

  const handleCapture = (uri: string, type: 'photo' | 'video') => {
 //   console.log('Capture:', uri, type);
 console.log("Capture: " + showMediaForm);
    setShowCamera(false);
    setCapturedMedia({ uri, type });
    setShowMediaForm(true);
  };

  const handleMediaFormSubmit = (mediaInfo: Omit<Image, 'id'>) => {
   // console.log('Media form submitted:', mediaInfo);
   console.log("MediaForm submitted: " + showMediaForm);
    setShowMediaForm(false);
    onMediaSelected(mediaInfo.uri, mediaInfo.type, mediaInfo.des, mediaInfo.coordinates);
  };
  
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Thêm ảnh/video</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={isModalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => setModalVisible(false)}
      >
        <View style={styles.modalOverlay}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.modalOption}
              onPress={handleCameraPress}
            >
              <Text style={styles.modalOptionText}>Chụp ảnh/quay video</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.modalOption}
              onPress={handleGalleryPress}
            >
              <Text style={styles.modalOptionText}>Chọn từ thư viện</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.modalCloseButton}
              onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.modalCloseButtonText}>Hủy</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>

      <Modal visible={showMediaForm} animationType="slide">
        {capturedMedia && (
          <MediaForm
            onSubmit={handleMediaFormSubmit}
            mediaUri={capturedMedia.uri}
            mediaType={capturedMedia.type}
          />
        )}
      </Modal>

      <Modal visible={showCamera} animationType="slide">
        <Camera onCapture={handleCapture} />
      </Modal>

     
    </View>
  );
}

Code media-form
const MediaForm: React.FC<MediaFormProps> = ({ onSubmit, mediaUri, mediaType }) => {
    console.log("MediaForm rendered with:", { mediaUri, mediaType });
    const [des, setDes] = useState('');
    const [lat, setLat] = useState('');
    const [lng, setLng] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log('Submitting form with:', { des, lat, lng });
        onSubmit({
            uri: mediaUri,
            des,
            coordinates: { lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lng) },
            type: mediaType,
        });
    };

    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
            behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
            style={styles.container}
        >
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Mô tả"
                value={des}
                onChangeText={setDes}
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Vĩ độ"
                value={lat}
                onChangeText={setLat}
                keyboardType="numeric"
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Kinh độ"
                value={lng}
                onChangeText={setLng}
                keyboardType="numeric"
            />
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button title="Lưu" onPress={handleSubmit} />
            </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
};


I tried using useEffect to monitor the state that controls the visibility of the media-form, but even though the state remains true, the form still hides.
If there is any solution other than using the modal library to manage the visibility of these components, please let me know. I would appreciate your help.
